# How to retrieve Swagger Definitions from java

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I annotated my various controller methods with swagger Annotations but now I want to be able to retrieve the info for a given method programmatically, e.g. I want to retrieve the APIOperation value and notes from within Java. Is that possible without me checking through all the Swagger Annotations?

Comment: It is possible. You have to use reflections to get annotation parameters' values.

Comment: I would expect that the Swagger library has an easy way to retrieve that info.

Comment: I you are using Spring, I think you can just inject the configured Docket bean(s) and check it out

Comment: And how do I do that if I don't want to use Spring?